# Writing L-Sentences - Logic

Tags: logic, quantifiers

Needing some help/guidance in how to write down $L$-sentences that express the following assertions. 
First let $L = {+, *, -, <, 0}$

1. If a real number has a square root, then its opposite does not.

   > $\forall x (0<x) \exists y (x*x=y \wedge -(x*x)\neq y)$. Not sure you can use the  $\neq$ though.
2. There exists a quadratic polynomial with real coefficients that has no real root.

   > I'm pretty stuck on this one. Guess: $\forall x,y,z \exists w (ax^2 + bx + cx = w) \wedge w$
3. Every positive integer is the sum of four squares.

   > $\forall x (x = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)$. I do not think I can use squares ($\cdot^2$) though since it is not in the language. So maybe: $\forall x(x = a*a + b*b + c*c + d*d)$
4. There are infinitely many positive even integers that can written as the difference of two squares.

   > $\forall x \exists y ((0<2x) \wedge y*y= (y-w)(y+w)$ I do not think this is correct.

Answer (score 2):

In the first two formulas, quantifiers are assumed to range over the reals. In the next two, they range over the integers. Note that there are many ways one can write something using our language.

The formulas below are on the fussy side. For example, there are lots of parentheses. They are technically necessary, but some could be omitted for the sake of readability. In the second question, so many parentheses were necessary that we gave up.

**First question:** The following sentence works:
$$\forall x\left(\exists y(y\ast y=x)\longrightarrow \lnot(\exists z (z\ast z=(0-x)))                             \right).$$
The above assertion is of course false, in the case $x=0$. If we wanted to write down a true sentence, we would modify the sentence suitably, by insisting that $x\ne 0$.

There is a little technical thing, I used $0-x$ instead of the natural $-x$, since presumably $-$ is a binary operator. If we want to get rid of "minus" entirely, we can, but since it is a formal part of the language you were given, we might as well use it.

**Second question:** We could say: 
$$\exists a\exists b\exists c\exists d\exists e\exists f\forall x\forall y\left(\lnot(a\ast (x\ast x)+b\ast(x\ast y)+c\ast(y\ast y)+d\ast x+e\ast y+f=0)\right)$$

**Third question:** 
$$\forall x\left((0\lt x)\longrightarrow \exists a\exists b\exists c\exists d(x=a\ast a+(b\ast b+(c\ast c+d\ast d)))                 \right).$$

**Fourth question:** Here, I will give a guide, so you can put it together yourself. To say there are infinitely $y$ with a certain property, we can say that for all $x$, there is a $y$ such that $x\lt y$ and $y$ has the property.

The property is now that $y+y$ is a difference of two squares. That is not difficult to say, particularly since we have $-$ as a a presumably binary operator.

Comment: It might prove interesting to at least know if we could prove all or some, or which ones, in Peano Arithmetic.

Comment: The first two are "about" the reals. And since we have a minus operator, presumably the next two are "about" the integers.  But analogous sentences could be made in the standard language of Peano arithmetic, and the true ones would be provable.

Comment: Nicolas You're right about the first two.  But, the four squares thesis just concerns the positive integers, which means the natural numbers... there's no subtraction there.  Also, S. C. Kleene had definitions for a type of subtraction on the natural numbers... but doesn't the incompleteness result imply that some true statements of elementary number theory aren't provable in a formal arithmetic?  Though, as I understand it, one of them depends on what we mean by "provable", and oftentimes things you might not expect even in number theory can get formally proved.

Comment: The Kleene subtraction (I am not sure it was Kleene, but I learned about it from a student of Kleene) is $-$ with a dot on top, ordinary $x\lt y$ if $x\ge y$, $0$ otherwise. The four squares is false unless we allow some $0$ squares.

Comment: Nicolas By a 0 square I'd guess you mean a square of 0... or do you mean a number to the "0th" power?  Either way (I'd like to know what you meant) I guess the resistance to thinking that the four squares thesis could get formalized lies in that it gets intended to hold for all positive integers.

Comment: A square $s$ is a number such that $\exists y(y\cdot y=s)$. What the variable ranges over is context dependent. For the four-squares theorem, we need to allow the possibility $y=0$, else the result fails. The theorem has many proofs. First-order PA is plenty strong enough for a proof.

Comment: Thanks.  If you ever get into one of those arguments about the incompleteness theorems, you might want to point that out to people who believe that such a result has destroyed logic/mathematics.